# Strapi Deployment to AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, strapi

I want to use Strapi and deploy to aws and website that expose many end points.

This app contain many end so it is going to be very heavy we want to use it.
We are using AWS Cloud services.

In addition, after development in the local development environment, it must be reviewed by the customer at the test server and updated to the production environment after that.

Therefore, Which aws service is best in regards to that with the low cost.

Which services are also good to use for our deployment options.
Is Docker good to have.
Backend(Strapi) is our technology which works on nodejs.
Is EC2 only option.
I am an IAM User
Help me Please!
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf8nm.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host any nodeJS application on AWS Lambda which is the serverless service.

What is serverless and AWS Lambda? [Answer here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/intro)

Yes you can host anything on EC2 but that should be the last option due to it's operations cost.

Hosting on containers is a good option. You can use AWS [ECS service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) + Application Load balancer to make your application Highly Available.

As per the error shown in the image it looks like account verification is not yet complete. Maybe open an AWS support ticket for this will help.

Comment: How should i use ecs any reference would help best.

Comment: This is a very open ended question. Please check the link I shared in my answer. Go through the documentation and ask a specific problem you're facing. If the answer helped you with the question you asked then please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I am an IAM User for a company